# indexPath not mutable? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to increment my indexPath using

```
selectedPrevious = mons[indexPath -= 1]
```

But I get the error stating **indexPath is a let constant**. There seems to be no way to change it to a variable however. I've tried creating and Int variable and assigning it to the index like so

```
index = indexPath.row -= 1
selectedPrevious = mons[index]
```

But now, trying to use `+=` or `-=` gives the new error.

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[Monster]' with an index of type '()'

How can I increment this. The intended purpose is to reload data in my second `Viewcontroller`. Just passing over the `index` variable by itself does not affect the data reload.

Comment: You want `let index = indexPath.row - 1` , or just `selectedPrevious = mons[indexPath.row - 1]`

Comment: The problem is when I call this then reload the data, it only calls it once, which was why I was trying to increment it.

Comment: If you want to increment indexpath.row just increment number of return row  at numberofrow method not indexpath.row .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter(arguments) passed to swift functions (pass by value) are `let` by default. What it means is you can read the value of the parameter that are passed to functions but you can not modify.

And this is applicable to all the variables not just the indexPath :)

So what you were doing was wrong :) If you want to modify the value of indexPath here is what you can do :)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        var copiedIndexPath = indexPath
        copiedIndexPath.row = copiedIndexPath.row + 1
}
```

As you can see I created a local copy of index path and modified its value :)

**EDIT :**

Statement

```
indexPath.row -= 1
```

not only will subtract the row of indexPath by one but will also try to assign the data back to indexPath which is let by default. If you really want to modify the indexPath value itself you can do what I mentioned above.

If your intention was simply to calculate the row index and not to modify the indexPath it self

```
index = indexPath.row - 1
```